# Is git pull --rebase the same as git pull when no work is done on the local master branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

I understand that the difference between `git rebase` and `git merge` is that `git rebase` moves the beginning of a branch to the tip of another branch, where as `git merge` creates a new commit that represents (i.e. includes or integrates) branched commits from another branch. So for example:

Since `git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch` + `git merge`, and `git pull --rebase` is equivalent to `git fetch` + `git rebase`, let's say you have a local master branch and a remote master branch:

```
- o - o - o - H - A - B - C (master)
               \
                P - Q - R (origin/master)
```

HEAD is at C

If you `git pull` you end up with this:

```
- o - o - o - H - A - B - C - X (master)
               \             /
                P - Q - R --- (origin/master)
```

HEAD will now be at X which is commit R of the remote repository's commit history because the merge commit (X) represents (i.e. includes or integrates) the remote branch's commit history that was merged

If on the other hand you did `git pull --rebase`, you would end up with this:

```
- o - o - o - H - P - Q - R - A' - B' - C' (master)
                          |
                          (origin/master)
```

As you can see `git pull` is not the same as `git pull --rebase` because `git pull --rebase` gives HEAD at C' which is commit C of the local master branch, where as when `git pull` was used HEAD was at R. In other words, contents of the commit history via `git pull` are the same as the contents of the commit history from `git pull --rebase`, but the order of commits in the commit histories is different

But what happens when you are pulling from a remote branch when no work has been done on the local master branch:

local master branch and a remote master branch:

```
- o - o - o - H (master)
               \
                P - Q - R (origin/master)
```

HEAD is at H

If you `git pull` you end up with this:

```
- o - o - o - H - X (master)
               \             \
                P - Q - R --- (origin/master)
```

HEAD will now be at X which is commit R of the repo because the merge commit represents the remote branch that was merged

If on the other hand you did `git pull --rebase`, would you end up with this?:

```
- o - o - o - H - P - Q - R (master)
                          |
                          (origin/master)
```

Meaning that HEAD is at R which means that `git pull --rebase` is the same as `git pull` when no work is done on the local branch

Comment: In your last example the two end results aren't exactly the same though...  (merge commit `X`) Codebase will be the same in both cases but not history traversal, so logs would be different.

Comment: Your assumption in the last `git pull` example is wrong, if you pull from remote and the local branch has no new commits, there *won't* be a new merge commit by default, but there will be a fast forward. 

You can change that behavior by forcing a merge commit to happen by adding `--no-ff`. To answer your question, **Yes**  pull and pull --rebase are the same if there is no local commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `git pull` runs `git merge`, it neither specifies `--ff-only` nor `--no-ff`, unless you specifically ask it to.

> [given the commit graph]
>
> ```
> ...--o--o--o--H   <-- master (HEAD)
>                \
>                 P--Q--R   <-- origin/master
> ```
>
> [you suggest that git merge, and therefore git pull, would produce]
>
> ```
> ...--o--o--o--H---------X   <-- master (HEAD)
>                \       /
>                 P--Q--R   <-- origin/master
> ```

This is not the case—not by default, anyway.  If you run `git merge --no-ff origin/master`, you *do* get this result.  If you run `git merge --ff-only`, or allow the default action, you get instead:

```
...--o--o--o--H
               \
                P--Q--R   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Git calls this a *fast-forward*.  When it's specifically `git merge` that does this,<sup>1</sup> Git calls it a *fast-forward merge*, although no actual merge takes place: Git really just does a `git checkout` of commit `R` while moving the branch name `master` so that it points to commit `R` (and leaving `HEAD` attached to branch name `master`).

The `--no-ff` option tells Git: *Do not do a fast-forward even if you can.*  The result is a new merge commit (or an error, or whatever else might go wrong, of course).  The `--ff-only` option tells Git: *If you can do a fast-forward, do it; if not, don't do anything, just error out.*

When you have `git pull` run `git merge`, you get the same set of options.  If a fast-forward is (a) possible and (b) permitted, the result of the `git merge` is the same as that of a `git rebase`: the name `master` gets updated and nothing inside the commit graph changes in any way.  If the fast-forward is *not* possible, or is inhibited via `--no-ff`, the result of a `git merge` differs from that of a `git rebase` in that there is a new merge commit `X`.

The *contents*—the saved snapshot—of your new merge commit `X` match those of your  commit `R`.  But since `R` and `X` are different commits, they have different hash IDs, and subsequent Git operations will behave differently.

---

<sup>1</sup>Both `git push` and `git fetch` can do this to references updated via refspecs.  When `git push` moves the server's branch in a fast-forward manner, you generally see nothing special.  When `git push` *cannot* move the branch this way, you normally get a rejection from the server.  The `git fetch` annotation, rather than `! rejected (non-fast-forward)`, is `(forced update)`.  (Well, that's one of three (!) `git fetch` annotations.)  See example immediately below.

What I like to emphasize here is that the fast-forwarding is a property of the label motion.  A fast-forward is possible if the commit identified before the motion—in this case commit `H`—is an ancestor of the commit to be identified afterward, i.e., commit `R`.

Here's an example of a non-fast-forward fetch update.  I have a local clone of the Git repository for Git.  One of the branches in the upstream is named `pu`, which stands for *proposed updates*.  This branch is regularly rewound and rebuilt with new commits: someone proposes some new feature, writes a first stab at it, and those go in for testing.  Bugs get found, the feature gets reworked, and the commits that went in are discarded in favor of new improved ones that go in to the `pu` branch.  So my `origin/pu` will be force-updated:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 509, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (214/214), done.
remote: Total 509 (delta 325), reused 400 (delta 295)
Receiving objects: 100% (509/509), 468.38 KiB | 1.52 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (325/325), done.
From [url]
   d8fdbe21b5..95628af9bb  next       -> origin/next
 + b6268ac8c6...465df7fb28 pu         -> origin/pu  (forced update)
   8051bb0ca1..f0bab95d47  todo       -> origin/todo
$
```

Note that my Git updated my `origin/next`, my `origin/pu`, and my `origin/todo`.  Two of these updates were fast-forward operations: commit `d8fdbe21b5` (my old `origin/next`) is an ancestor of `95628af9bb` (my updated `origin/next`), for instance.  But `b6268ac8c6`, my old `origin/pu`, is *not* an ancestor of `465df7fb28`.  My Git updated my `origin/pu` *anyway*, losing access to commit `b6268ac8c6` (except via reflogs).

To announce this fact, `git fetch`:

1. prefixed the line with `+`;
2. printed *three* dots in the update, instead of two; and
3. added `(forced update)` at the end of the line.

Because the changes to `origin/next` and `origin/todo` *were* fast-forward operations, my Git said nothing extra about them.

Comment: Very insightful explanation on how `git merge` and `git rebase` work. This quote "*Git really just does a git checkout of commit R while moving the branch name master so that it points to commit R (and leaving HEAD attached to branch name master).*", explains the 3rd commit graph perfectly. When you say "*The contents—the saved snapshot—of your new merge commit X match those of your commit R*", can I confirm you mean that merger commit `X` is the same as the remote branch commit `R`? What are some examples of how subsequent Git operations behave differently between merge commit `x` and `R`?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia: (1) I mean that the *tree* in `X` and `R` will match. The tree, or saved snapshot, is the set of files you'll get in your index and work-tree when you check out that particular commit. Obviously the commits themselves don't match in other ways: `X` has two parents, and probably a different date-and-time stamp.

Comment: (2) Anything you do in the future that walks the commit graph will, upon reaching a merge like `X`, follow *both* parents unless directed otherwise. So `git log` would show `X`, then show both parents (`H` and `R`), and `R`'s parent, and so on. The *order* in which these commits get shown becomes a bit tricky. With the fast-forward, there's a simple linear chain, and it's easy to reason about how future Git operations walk backwards along the chain, one commit at a time.

Comment: Does "*can do this*" in "*Both git push and git fetch can do this to references updated via refspecs.*" mean `git push` and `git fetch` can do a fast forward? "*When git push moves the server's branch in a fast-forward manner, you generally see nothing special.*" so does this mean that you can only `git push` to a remote branch (i.e. a server's branch)  when a fast forward is possible?

Comment: "*When git push cannot move the branch this way, you normally get a rejection from the server.*", is this why you always need to `git pull` when your remote branch has diverged from the local master (i.e. the remote branch cannot be fast forwarded since the remote branch diverged from the local branch which tracks it)? Can you clarify thefollowing sentence "*The git fetch annotation, rather than ! rejected (non-fast-forward), is (forced update). (Well, that's one of three (!) git fetch annotations.)*", it's confusing.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia: consider, e.g., `git push . x:y` where `x` and `x` are both branch names. The `.` as the name of the remote has your Git call up *itself*, so that it's handling both sides of the transaction. Your Git first offers to itself any commits you don't already have—obviously this is a no-op!—and then asks itself: *please, if you will, set the hash ID for branch `y` to the hash ID I got by resolving branch name `x`*. Your Git will obey its own request if and only if the commit identified by `y` is an ancestor of the one that it's been asked to update-to.

Comment: If you use a different Git (e.g., `git push origin x:y`), all the steps are the same, though your commit identified by `x` might have to go to the remote Git at `origin` first. After that, though, your Git asks them to please set their `y` to the hash ID from your `x`. And, yes, that's why the usual thing is to fetch-and-(rebase-or-merge): the result is that your new branch tip is a fast-forward operation for them.

Comment: I'll edit the fetch non-fast-forward part into footnote-by-example, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the last paragraph in your answer. In particular I do not understand what you mean by "label motion". In that paragraph you say "*A fast-forward is possible if the commit identified before the motion—in this case commit H—is an ancestor of the commit to be identified afterward, i.e., commit R.", does this mean the same as saying that a fast-forward is only possible when you merge a branch that is ahead of your checked out branch, in other words the merged branch is ahead of checkedout branch which means commit H is an ancestor of R so a fast-forward is possible?

Comment: See the updated footnote, and note that the labels in the example are the three remote-tracking names `refs/remotes/origin/next`, `refs/remotes/origin/pu`, and `refs/remotes/origin/todo` (which Git abbreviates for display purposes).

Comment: I created a master branch and feature branch, and merged them using `--no-ff` to test the order in which merged commits are shown using `git log`. `git log` walks the commit graph backwards in the order of most recent commits. So `git log` shows commit `X`, then one of `X`'s parent, commit `R`, then `R`'s parent which is `Q`, then `P`, then the other parent of `X` i.e. H. The observation of this commit chain seems quite linear to me, just as I would expect from a fast-forward merge. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's because in this case the sort order *is* going to go that way. See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering), but note that it's not complete: the order is determined by placing commits into, then taking them out of, a priority queue. When starting from a branch tip, the priority queue contains only one commit—the branch tip—so that's the one shown. Showing the commit puts its parents into the queue, and when that commit is not a merge, there's just one parent, so the queue remains depth 1.

Comment: To get a more complex sort, either (a) start with more than one commit—`git log master dev` for instance—or (b) have the graph-walk reach a merge commit. At this point, the visit order (or really, priority in the queue) defaults to committer date, with lots of exceptions, including those from command-line options and things like `--topo-order`.